# Link in mailto body was changed

Tags: html, email, outlook, mailto

when i sent mailto like that:

```
mailto:?subject=D2%20link%20to%20DOC&body=I%20thought%20you%20might%20find%20this%20%20Doc%20information%20interesting%3A%20http%3A//15.55.11.34%3A8080/E5/servlet/Download%3Fauth%3Dbasic%26event_name%3Dopen%26id%3Dtest
```

its in my outlook look like:

[image]

how can i fix that?
the link are broken because the "http://"...

tnx a lot

Comment: Maybe you need to convert slashes as well to `%2F` - also try [this decoder](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Comment: i used escape function and encodeURI function same thing happend...

Comment: That is indeed weird. I tested it with google inbox and your `href` works just fine. Sadly I don't have Outlook, so I can't test it